# How create link in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jQuery notification. When I click on the notification it should go the intended page.

In PHP we can achieve that by doing following.

```
$link = 22;
echo "<a href=\"page2.php?id=link\">Click to read more</a>";
```

How to achieve such in JQuery? I have notification pop up and link variable ready.

```
var link = "home.php?destination=22";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create HTML element using jQuery

```js
var link = "home.php?destination=22";

//Create anchor element
var anchor = $('<a />', {
  "href": link,
  "text": "Click to read more"
})

//Append the element
$('#dialog').append(anchor).dialog();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  
</div>
```

Comment: How can I put the link in on line, lets say in alert()? When I put anchor in alert it becomes object. Example alert(anchor);

Comment: Please help me put the link in alert();

Comment: the link is not working. It just stays as plain text.

Comment: Is it possible to make linkable text in jquery?

Comment: @tapaljor, Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it using `window.location.href` in java script.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me to read more</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.location.href = 'home.php?destination=22';
}
</script>
```